# How do you create properties in CruiseControl.Net

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

In ant scripts and MS build files you can set properties at the top how do I do this in the CruiseControl file ccnet.config?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with cb:define.  For example:

<cb:define myProjectName="Foo"/>

Then to use the defined property:

<project name="$(myProjectName)" queue="Bar">
</project>

More information about cb:define can be found here:

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor

Comment: @Dustin: do cb:define tags need to be at the root of the document or can they occur anywhere?

Comment: They can be anywhere.  However, I believe that they need to occur before the first use of the property that you are defining.

Answer (score 3):

`<cb:define />` creates a pre-processor constant, not a property.  Pre-processor constants have global scope and may be defined only once.  A property would be scoped to the block in which it is created and could be overloaded with the same name in a different block.  You can use the `<cb:scope>` tag to modify the scope of the pre-processor constant and mimic properties, as shown here:

[CruiseControl.NET : Configuration Preprocessor](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Configuration%20Preprocessor.html)